# PathFile Access Error when saving in G drive directory

Tags: excel, vba

So the issue is as follows.
I have created a VBA task that runs a query that returns some insignificant amount of data in our databases. It then does some simple calculations in the excel file, and finally it creates a new folder and it the saves the file to our department shared drive in Google Drive (we have a windows explorer path to the directory named G drive).

It works ok on my end but now I have sent the whole .xlsm file to my collegue and once she run the vba code, it throws an error saying Path/File Access Error. We have tried chaning the directory where it creates a folder and saves the file on her local C drive, and it works just fine.

Any ideas how to remedy this issue?

Comment: use a standardized path that everyone has.  The original path seems to be specific to your system and isn't available on your colleague's system.

Comment: You may want to consider using a UNC file path instead if it's on a network.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of uploading to a windows explorer path, you should upload to an absolute path of google drive, as that is the same no matter who tries to access it. There is a guide here that accomplishes exactly that:
https://medium.com/coalmont/google-drive-api-using-excel-vba-80e3d7e41488

If for some reason that guide is not available, just google something like "vba excel upload google drive".